# jQuery content controller isn't showing and hiding content properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make a navigation bar for the past couple days, but I seem to run into a lot of problems with it. Right now my problem is the jQuery, it doesn't function the way I want it to:

I would like a single page website, so whenever I click a navigation bar the current page should hide and the targeted page should show. Right now, some of the pages still stack on top of eachother, can someone please help me?

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Yu-Gi-Oh! Stash</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/contentcontroller.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/navbar.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>        
        <section> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#decks">Decks &blacktriangledown;</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#decks_starter-decks">Starter Decks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#decks_structure-decks">Structure Decks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#booster-packs">Booster Packs &blacktriangledown;</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#booster-packs_booster-sets">Booster Sets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#booster-packs_special-edition">Special Editions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#booster-packs_duelist-packs">Duelist Packs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#booster-packs_master-collections">Master Collections</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#torunament-awards">Tournament Awards</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#promotions">Promotions &blacktriangledown;</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#promotions_video-games">Video Games</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#promotions_entertainments">Entertainment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#promotions_foundations">Foundations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="decks" class="tab-content active">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Decks</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="decks_starter-decks" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Starter Decks</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="decks_structure-decks" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Structure Decks</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="booster-packs" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Booster Packs</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="booster-packs_booster-sets" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Booster Sets</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="booster-packs_special-edition" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Special Edition</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="booster-packs_duelist-packs" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Duelist Packs</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="booster-packs_master-collections" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Master Collections</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="torunament-awards" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Tournament Awards</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="promotions" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Promotions</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="promotions_video-games" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Video Game Promotions</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="promotions_entertainments" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Magazine, Movie & McDonalds Promotions</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>

            <section id="promotions_foundations" class="tab-content hide">
                <h1 class="page-heading">Foundations</h1>

                <p>lorem ipsum..</p>
            </section>
        </section>

        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 35px 25px 25px 25px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

section {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: 1000px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

section section {
    border: none;
}

.page-heading {
    margin: 80px 0px 80px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #06b;
}

/********************
 ***NAVIGATION BAR***
 ********************/
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
    margin: -1px 0px 0px -1px;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-top: none;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

nav:after {
    clear: both;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px -1px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li.active > a {
    color: #06b;
    border-color: #aaa #aaa #fff;
}

nav ul li:hover > a {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #aaa #aaa #fff;
}

nav ul a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    color: #09c;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #eee #eee transparent;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 150%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-top: none;
    border-color: #eee !important;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
    border-color: #aaa !important;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/*************
 ***CONTENT***
 *************/
.tab-content.active {
    display: block;
}

.tab-content.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery code

```
/***************************
 ***Navbar click function***
 ***************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav li > a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //declare current tab content
        var current_tab_content = $('nav li.active > a').attr('href');

        //hide current tab content
        $(current_tab_content).removeClass('active').addClass('hide');

        //show targeted tab content
        var targeted_tab_content = $(this).attr('href');
        $(targeted_tab_content).removeClass('hide').addClass('active');

        //remove 'active' from current navbar
        var current_navbar = $('nav li.active');
        $(current_navbar).removeClass('active');

        //add 'active' to clicked navbar
        $(this).parents('li').last().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Apperantly the pages stack if you select a page that is higher in the dropdown, than the previous. For example, if you are on "Structure Decks" and click "Starter Decks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you end up with more than one section with the class 'active' after clicking the nav a few times.

Try hiding all sections first, then showing the desired one rather than hiding a single tab at a time:

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('active').addClass('hide');
$(targeted_tab_content).addClass('active').removeClass('hide');
```

**Other Suggestions**

1. You could potentially only have one class instead of two, default everything to `display: none;` and then you only have to remove/assign the 'active' class.
2. There is also a jQuery function for `show()` and `hide()` that could be useful here.

Comment: You were right, and your solution almost did it for me. To make it work I removed the 'active' from all .tab-content and added 'hide' to all .tab-content at the same time and then it worked! Thanks